# How to insert duplicate data from other table into primary key column using T-SQL?

Tags: csv, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three tables for my project, `Media`, `Program` and `ProgramMedia`.

`Media` table:

```
MediaId (PK, int, not null), Name (varchar(100), not null)
```

`Program` table:

```
ProgramId (PK, int, not null), Topic (varchar(100), null), 
MediaList (varchar(200), not null)
```

`ProgramMedia` table:

```
ProgramId (PK, FK, int, not null), MediaId (PK, FK, int, not null)
```

`Media` and `Program` table already have values like this:

`Media` table

```
(11, 'GoodNews'), 
(22, 'UniversalTV'), 
(33, 'Master')
```

`Program` table

```
(1, 'Goverment', '11, 33'),
(2, 'Education', '22, 33')
```

I want to split the `MediaList` column into `ProgramMedia` table. So the display will be like this:

`ProgramMedia` table

```
(1, 11), (1, 33), (2, 22), (2, 33)
```

And the `MediaList` column will be deleted.

I have tried to split the column, but my problem is it couldn't insert to `ProgramMedia` table because the it has a primary key.

I can't solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Primary Key must be unique. Your PK is on ProgramId and you want to insert ProgramId twice with value 1 and twice with value 2.

If ProgramId + MediaId are unique, you can chage your primary key to:

```
ALTER TABLE ProgramMedia 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ProgramMedia 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProgramId, MediaId);
```

You can also add an identity column and use it as your PK:

```
ALTER TABLE tt Add [id] int identity(0, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```